# Subquery in the where clause

Tags: sql, subquery, correlated-subquery

Hard to google this one, bear with me...looking for rarer syntax. Is there a query like this:

```
SELECT x
FROM foo 
WHERE foo.y = (foo.a = 3 AND foo.b = 5)
```

basically the expression within the parens evaluates to a boolean, and I wonder if that can be used to lookup the y column (which stores a boolean values).
This syntax is probably wrong, does someone know if there is something like this that exists?

Comment: Hi @rakim, if you can post your table structure and some sample data, perhaps people can better see what you are asking.

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: if `foo.y` is indeed a boolean column the your expression is valid SQL, see here: https://rextester.com/VVZR80996 - however only a few DBMS system support a proper boolean data type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE` expression like this:

```
SELECT x
from foo 
where foo.y = (CASE WHEN (foo.a = 3 AND foo.b = 5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Comment: If `foo.y` is indeed a `boolean` there is no need for a case expression. `foo.y = (foo.a = 3 AND foo.b = 5)` would work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IFF(),using `SQL Server`, as following:

```
select x 
from foo
where foo.y = (select iif(foo.a=3 and foo.b=5,0,1));
```

[DB Fiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=14a9d326a01d66a4d45095c2e020c8bf)

Comment: It is for SQL Server